# Laptop network driver issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers, internet

So I have an hp envy 15 laptop. I recently restored it to factory settings becuz it was Slow.
 Now for some reason my internet isn't connecting thru Wi-Fi.
 I can connect with ethernet but Wi-Fi doesn't show networks or it will show for a minute then disappear.
 I went on the hp website and downloaded and installed network drivers for my laptop but it didn't work.
My internet still isn't connecting thru Wi-Fi

Comment: Make sure to get the drivers for the exact model you have. Similar models may have different wireless adapters.